# Selecting values from column according to a specific value in different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am kinda stuck on selecting values from one column according to a specific value form a different column. For example, the following dataframe:

```
 name   profit 

Anna    10000
Alice   5000 
Anna    500
Anna    4000
Jack    2000
```

I am trying to get the mean of Anna's profit values from the profit column.
I tried using `df['name'].str.contains('Anna')` to select Anna from the name column, however, I'm not sure how I can go about selecting the profit values where it's only Anna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `query`:

```
df.query('name == "Anna"')['profit'].mean()
```

Or `eq` and slicing:

```
df.loc[df['name'].eq('Anna'), 'profit'].mean()
```

variant:

```
df[df['name'].eq('Anna')]['profit'].mean()
```

output: `4833.33`

Comment: I voted for your 2nd answer for readability.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `mask`:

```
>>> df.mask(~df['name'].str.contains('Anna'))['profit'].mean()
4833.333333333333
```